# Keep getting 500 error on request for data from table with compound key

Tags: mysql, vue.js, express, nuxt.js

I am using Vue with Nuxt, axios, MySQL and Express.  I have tables for `members`, `concerts`, and `rsvps`.  The members and concerts have primary keys, but the rsvps is a compound key of `MemberD` and `ConcertID`.  Using `asyncData`, I am able to show all rsvps for all members and concerts, separated by instrument types, but when I try to edit an individual member’s rsvps for all future concerts, I get a `500 error`.   I’ve now spent several days trying different tweaks to the code, but have come up with the same error.  I think it may have to do with the fact that each member can have several concerts, each of which has both an `RSVPValue` and a Comment.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  This is my `rsvpsController` code for all rsvps and for updating a single member’s rsvps:

```js
module.exports.list = function (req, res, next) {             
  con.query('SELECT *, rsvps.MemberID as id, members.MemberID, members.instrumentID, instruments.instrumentID, instruments.name, concerts.concertID, concerts.concertDate, concerts.concertTime, concerts.locationID, locations.locationID, locations.locationName FROM rsvps INNER JOIN members ON rsvps.MemberID = members.MemberID INNER JOIN instruments ON members.instrumentID = instruments.instrumentID INNER JOIN concerts ON rsvps.concertID = concerts.concertID INNER JOIN locations ON concerts.locationID = locations.locationID WHERE concertDate >= CURDATE() ORDER BY name, lastname, concertDate', function (err, results, fields) {
    if(err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
          message: 'Error getting records.',
          err: err
      });
    }

    if(results.length>0){
      return res.json(results);
    }
    else{
      return res.json([]);
    }
  });
}
```

This is my `rsvpsController` code for updating a single member's rsvps:

```js
module.exports.update = [
  // validation rules
  validator.body('MemberID', 'Please enter Member ID').isLength({ min: 1 }),  
  
  function(req, res) {
    // throw validation errors
    const errors = validator.validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.mapped() });
    }

    var id = req.params.id;

    // Update only if record exists
    con.query('SELECT *, rsvps.MemberID as id, members.MemberID, members.firstname, members.lastname from rsvps INNER JOIN members on rsvps.MemberID = members.MemberID WHERE rsvps.MemberID = ? ORDER BY ConcertID', [id], function(err, results, fields) {
      if(err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: 'Error getting record.',
            err: err
        });
      }

      // Perform Update if record found
      if(results.length>0){
        const rsvps = ([results])

        // initialize record
        rsvps.ConcertID =  req.body.ConcertID ? req.body.ConcertID : rsvps.ConcertID;
        rsvps.MemberID = req.body.MemberID ? req.body.MemberID : rsvps.MemberID
        rsvps.Comment = req.body.Comment ? req.body.Comment : rsvps.Comment
        rsvps.RSVPValue = req.body.RSVPValue ? req.body.RSVPValue : rsvps.RSVPValue
        
        // save record
      //  con.query('UPDATE playlists SET ? WHERE concertID=?', [playlist, id], function (err, results, fields) {
        con.query('UPDATE rsvps SET ? WHERE MemberID=?', [id], function (err, results, fields) {
          if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
              message: 'Error saving record',
              err: err
            });
          }
          return res.json([rsvps]);
        });

      }
      else{
        return res.status(404).json({
          message: 'No such record'
        });
      }
    });
  }
]
```

And this is my update page, found in `pages/rsvps/id/update.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div class="flex w-11/12 bg m-auto place-content-between">
    <div class="bg-white m-4 p-4 w-1/3 rounded-md">      
    
      <form action="" method="POST" @submit.prevent="submitForm">
        <div class="center font-semibold w-full">
          <p> Update RSVPs for {{ rsvp.firstName }} {{ rsvp.lastname }}:  {{ rsvp.id }} </p>
        </div>           
        <div v-for="concert in sortedFutureConcerts" :key="concert.id" class="w-full">
          <div v-for="item in rsvps" v-if="concert.id == rsvps.ConcertID">
            {{ concert.locationName }}, {{ formDate(concert.concertDate) }} {{ concert.fullband == 1 ? 'Full Band' : '' }} {{ concert.german ==1 ? 'OTB' : '' }} {{ concert.dixieland == 1 ? 'Dixieland' : '' }} 
          </div> 
              
          <div class="bg-gray-100">
            <input type="radio" name="RSVPValue" v-model="RSVPValue" id="Yes" value="Yes" v-if="RSVPValue == 'Yes' ? ' checked=\'checked\'' : 'unchecked'"/> <label for="Yes">Yes&nbsp&nbsp</label>
            <input type="radio" name="RSVPValue" v-model="RSVPValue" id="No" value="No" v-if="RSVPValue == 'No' ? ' checked=\'checked\'' : 'unchecked'"/> <label for="No">No&nbsp&nbsp</label>
            <input type="radio" name="RSVPValue" v-model="RSVPValue" id="Maybe" value="Maybe" v-if="RSVPValue == 'Maybe' ? ' checked=\'checked\'' : 'unchecked'"/> <label for="Maybe">Maybe&nbsp&nbsp</label>
            <input type="radio" name="RSVPValue" v-model="RSVPValue" id="Awaiting" value="Awaiting" v-if="i == 'Awaiting' ? ' checked=\'checked\'' : 'unchecked'"/> <label for="Awaiting">Awaiting&nbsp&nbsp</label>
          </div> <br><br>
          <p>Comment</p>
          <textarea v-model="Comment" placeholder="Limit 100 characters">{{ item.Comment }}</textarea>       
          
        </div> 
        <div class="flex mt-3">
          <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn rounded ml-4 mr-4">
            Save
          </button>
          <button type="reset" value="Cancel" @click="toAdmin" class="btn rounded mr-4">
            Cancel
          </button>
        </div>
      </form> 
    </div>   
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {  
  async asyncData({$axios, params}) {
    const [ concerts, rsvps ] = await Promise.all([
      $axios.$get('/api/concerts'),
      $axios.$get('/api/rsvps/' + params.id)
    ])
    console.log(rsvps)
    return { concerts, rsvps }
  }, 
  
  middleware: 'auth',

  data() {
    return {
      rsvps: [],
      concerts:[],
      ConcertID:null,
      MemberID:null,
      Comment:null,
      RSVPValue:null  
    }
  },
  computed: {    
    sortedFutureConcerts() {        
      return this.concerts.filter(s => new Date(s.concertDate) >= new Date())
        .sort((a, b) => new Date(a.concertDate) - new Date(b.concertDate))
    }     
  },
  mounted(){
      this.fillFormData()
  },
 
  methods: {
    fillFormData(){  
    //  this.ConcertID = this.sortedFutureConcerts.id
    //  this.MemberID = this.rsvp.MemberID
      this.Comment = this.rsvp.Comment
      this.RSVPValue = this.rsvp.RSVPValue      
    },

    formDate(dd) {    
      let sub = dd.substring(0,10)
      let newD = sub.split("-")    
      let dte = new Date(Date.UTC(newD[0], newD[1], newD[2]))
      const options = { weekday: 'short', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' }
      let dForm = dte.toLocaleDateString(undefined, options)       
      return dForm
    },
     
    submitForm(){
      this.$axios.post( '/api/rsvps', {                            
        ConcertID: this.sortedFutureConcerts.id,
        MemberID: this.params.id,
        Comment: this.Comment,
        RSVPValue: this.RSVPValue          
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        if(response.data.id){    //.id){
          this.$router.push({ name:'admin', params:{ created:'yes' } })
        }
      })
      .catch( (error) => {
        console.log(error)
        if(error.response.data.errors){
          this.errors = error.response.data.errors
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.btn {
  border: 1px solid darkslategray;
  padding: 2px 2px;
}
.min {
  min-height: 100px;  
}
</style>
```

Comment: You did not found where the 500 was coming from? No logs on the backend?

Comment: My console says (node:17236)  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 500

Comment: Where does this one comes from (in your code)? Try to find where this error could happen by back-tracking the possible use cases and using some Google-fu!

Comment: I have never done use cases, so this is foreign to me.  I decided to do a work-around by getting all the rsvps and filtering out everything except for the concertID I wanted, since listing all the rsvps worked.  Thank you for your thoughts; I will need to look into use cases and working on the back end to find errors.  I just need to get this working for now.